# Create rounded corners and curved bottom shape with Windows.Shapes.Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, shapes

I'm looking to create the following shape in XAML with System.Windows.Shapes.Path
[image]

(The image is a bit rough but demonstrates the curved corners in the top left and right and the curved bottom image).

So far I have the bottom curve with the following:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L300,0 L300,40.768158 L296.83832,41.189522 C253.5976,46.794456 203.45944,50.000004 150,50.000004 C96.540565,50.000004 46.402409,46.794456 3.1617098,41.189522 L0,40.768158" ... />
```

But I am unsure how to get the top corners to be rounded with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use elliptical arcs (class [ArcSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx)) in your Path geometry:

```
<Path Fill="Black"
      Data="M0,20 A20,20 0 0 1 20,0 L280,0 A20,20 0 0 1 300,20 L300,150 A150,75 0 0 1 0,150 Z"/>
```

Alternatively you could use a [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653071.aspx) like this:

```
<Path Fill="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,300,170" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="150,150" RadiusX="150" RadiusY="75"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Both solutions made the shape I wanted perfectly - thank you. 
I used the second option as it is easier for me to change the size of the shape as required.